# how to implement perceptron test

Tags: java, machine-learning, perceptron

I have an implementation of the perceptron algorithm, which operates according to the bag-of-words model, defining a series of weights to seperate two feature vectors.

Example:

```
Document 1 = ["I", "am", "awesome"]
Document 2 = ["I", "am", "great", "great"]
```

Dictionary is:

```
["I", "am", "awesome", "great"]
```

So the documents as a vector would look like:

```
Document 1 = [1, 1, 1, 0]
Document 2 = [1, 1, 0, 2]
```

The algorithm then learns a Decision boundary equation, i.e.:

```
feature_0 * weight_0 +
feature_1 * weight_1 +
feature_2 * weight_2 +
feature_3 * weight_3 +
bias
```

Now I have a test set which, in format is very similar to the training set depicted above. What is the psuedocode to test these values against my decision boundary equation and thereby assign them labels?

I guess it's something like (pseudocode):

```
For each word in the test set
    if that word exists in the global dict
        value = the frequency of that word * the learned weight
            if value >= 0
                return 1
            else
                return -1
```

But I want to capture the class of the entire feature vector, not just one word, so I guess it must be a summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. Training and test set need to have the *exact* same format. To test, you just solve the equation for known weights and features (of your test set).

In principle, you should generate test and training data together to ensure they're as equal as possible - and then split them into two sets. Generating test data (i.e. the labels) depending on how the decision boundary is set is a very bad idea: The main idea of the test set is to test the current trained boundary against data that follows an unknown, *real* boundary. By inducing knowledge into the system your test results will badly reflect the *real* accuracy.

Comment: i think i got it, could you take a look at my code to see if you agree? It's on my [github page](https://github.com/h1395010/perceptron/blob/master/src/file_dict_createur/Perceptron.java) I commented where I do the test.

Comment: Seems correct to me but don't take it for granted since I'm a bit tired atm :) If everything is correct you can set test=train set and should get nearly 100% with the right parameters.

Comment: so, i can switch the test set and the training set in that perceptron class? i guess if i were to do that i would have to initialize my weights to zero rather than a random number isn't it? and then i should get the same result?

Comment: What you're looking for is called k-fold validation: See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation)